quiver in latex with dots

how can i write this ??
i tried $\overset{\bullet}1$  $\overset{\bullet}2$ but i can't write arrow.

this?
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \bullet\arrow[d, controls={+(-2,0) and +(-2,0)}] & \bullet \\
        1 & 2
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{document}



You were really helpful, thanks.

@wanheda  If my answer was helpful, please accept it (there is a button to click on the left side of the answer)
